# C++ pointers and optimization

Tags: c++, pointers, optimization

I have read that the C++ compiler does the optimization for you (,or at least should) and that the programmer shouldn't worry **too much** about it.

But how does this compare to pointers? It seems that every time you make a function you have to decide whether to use pointers or not. What's the reason behind this? Shouldn't the compiler do this for you as far as possible?

And isn't there a keyword which you can use in the method signature that states that the objects given as parameter won't be mutated so that the compiler could optimize stuff?

And why is(n't) there one?

Comment: Please provide references of *what you heard or read*. Not sure what you're aiming at.

Comment: I really don't very often have a tough decision of whether to use pointers.

Comment: Don't use pointers unless there is no other option. Problem solved

Comment: There's no problem, there's only a question from someone who's trying to learn it all. Secondly, I don't see that as an option since it's a big feature in c++.

Comment: A great many things you would use pointers for in C can be done with references in C++. For the rest, consider this generic advice: 1) `new` in constructors, `delete` in destructors, and 2) [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/memory) anythere you cannot stick to rule #1. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar I'd state the rules the other way round - only use manual `new` and `delete` if an existing smart pointer doesn't work for you.

Comment: @Angew: In which order doesn't really matter that much as being aware of the pains that "naked" pointers can bring, especially once you toss exceptions into the arena. ;-)

Comment: It's not a big feature in C++. It's a hangover from C that is being phased out as much as possible. Modern C++ almost never involves raw pointers.

Comment: @MattMcNabb *Owning* raw pointers, I would say. They're still perfectly fine as non-owning observers (although they're of course not used as often as in C).

Comment: @Angew see [N3840](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3840.pdf)

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yup, I know of that one. Is it part of a standard (or draft) now?

Comment: @Angew No idea, but my point is that the language is moving in the direction of avoiding raw pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using object as argument, a compiler may or may not do the [copy ellision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) depending on many factors. If in doubt compiler can make a safe assumption that function may want to change the argument and may avoid copy elision optimization.

Instead if you use (const) reference or a pointer, it provides **stronger guarantee** to the compiler that either object won't change or changes done locally in the function are required in the caller also.

In general one should avoid avoid micro optimizations unless proven bottleneck using some profiling and concentrate on readability of code for better maintenance and architectural changes which can give higher optimization and can not be suggested/performed by tools.